# The time that Jmeter spends during script execution

Tags: performance, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I executed a script simulating 950 VU in 10 seconds, but Jmeter last 23 minutes in finish the test.
I guess that Jmeter doesn't finish the test until it completes the number of threads of the test, and that depends on the server response time.

Does it work like that or on what the finish time depends?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter waits for the response, if your server has problems it may wait a lot.

Usually, it is advised to add [HTTP Request Default](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) and configured:

- connect timeout
- read timeout

To acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts as follows:

1. It starts the number of threads defined in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) within the ramp-up period time frame.
2. Each thread starts executing [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
3. JMeter executes samplers **as fast as it can** (unless you're using [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) in your Test Plan, and should be doing this in order to mimic real user think time)
4. When there are no more samplers to execute or loops to iterate the thread is being shut down
5. When there are no more running (or sleeping) threads - the test ends.

Recommendations:

- If you want your test to take not longer than X seconds you can use "Scheduler" section of the Thread Group to specify desired test duration.
- The same can be achieved using [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)
- Given "as fast as it can" stanza at point 3 JMeter itself might be the bottleneck. JMeter default configuration is not suitable for high loads, it is OK for tests development and debugging so make sure you follow instructions from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) to ensure that JMeter configuration is optimal.